# Что это за оператор

Tags: groovy, тернарный-оператор

Не могу понять что означает эта строка кода
type = null == type ? null : type.toLowerCase();

Comment: `if (то что до знака вопроса истинно)` вернуть то что до двоеточия `else` вернуть то что после двоеточия

Comment: Не совсем понял что означает именно условие type = null == type, здесь type String

Comment: условие здесь `null == type`, а до него идет присвоение

Comment: т.е String type; type = null; if(null == type){return null} else{}

Comment: type присвоить значение null если type - null, а если type не null, то в нижний регистр перевести. Так?

Comment: да, именно так и есть

Comment: Спасибо,  Stranger in the Q. Просто как-то странно, что null сравнивают с переменной, обычно же наоборот.

Comment: в целом нет, т.к. ксли первым идет null то меньше вероятность NPE

Answer (score 1):

Это называется тернарный оператор. Работает таким образом: `var = (условие)? {значение если условие верно} : {значение если условие не верное}`

В указанной строчке кода проверяется наличие значения у переменной `type`, для того, чтобы избежать `NullPointerException` Если у переменной `type` есть значение, она будет переведена в нижний регистр.

С моей точки зрения, куда лучше и понятнее было бы написать так:

```
if (type != null) {
    type = type.toLowerCase()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Меня вот именно и смутило, что написано не так, как Вы предложили.